# Keycloak script mapper option missing in 9.0.3

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-services

I am running version keycloak-9.0.3 and dont have script mapper. I tried adding profile.properties but it did not bring this option under the drop down in mapper type.

Answer (score 0):

In [Keycloak Server Developer Guide](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/10.0/server_development/index.html#using-keycloak-administration-console-to-upload-scripts),

> Ability to upload scripts through the admin console is deprecated and will be removed in a future version of Keycloak
>
> ...
>
> For more details about how to enable the `upload_scripts` feature. Please, take a look at the [Profiles](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/10.0/server_installation/#profiles).

So you can see "Script Mapper" option under the drop down if you start your Keycloak server with:

```
-Dkeycloak.profile.feature.upload_scripts=enabled
```